# kubeadm upgrade plan warning when updaten from 1.23 to 1.24

Tags: kubernetes, containerd

A few weeks ago I upgraded kubernetes 1.22 to 1.23. I'm using containerd as container runtime a long time.

Now when upgrading from 1.23 to 1.24 `kubeadm upgrade plan` show warning about runtime as

```
W0917 12:14:33.970744   27728 initconfiguration.go:120] Usage of CRI endpoints without URL scheme is deprecated and can cause kubelet errors in the future. Automatically prepending scheme "unix" to the "criSocket" with value "/run/containerd/containerd.sock". Please update your configuration!
```

I have made quite lot of reserch to find out, where to add/fix setting to get out of this warning. Config-changes I have made at least `/var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env` and `/etc/crictl.yaml` files, but there is no success. Anybody?

Comment: Consider to ask sys-admin questions on https://serverfault.com instead. Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Answer (score 1):

Run this command on your control plane and nodes.

```
sudo crictl config \
--set runtime-endpoint=unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock \
--set image-endpoint=unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock
```